# JGit rebase keep local files and get conflict files list

Tags: git, rebase, jgit

I am trying to rebase mybranch from origin/mybranch. I am using this code:

```
git.pull().setRebase(true).setRemoteBranchName(branch).call();
```

After doing this, conflicting files are getting updated with the comments like

> <<<<<<< Upstream, based on branch

but local changes without conflict are getting overwritten with the repository content even though I have committed my local changes.

Instead of calling this function if I tried to run git command "git rebase" in command prompt, local files are not getting updated, so it's fine.

Later I tried the following link approach,

https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/RebaseToOriginMaster.java

```
InteractiveHandler handler = new InteractiveHandler() {
    @Override
    public void prepareSteps(List<RebaseTodoLine> steps) {
        for(RebaseTodoLine step : steps) {
            try {
                step.setAction(Action.EDIT);
            } catch (IllegalTodoFileModification e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String modifyCommitMessage(String oldMessage) {
        return oldMessage;
    }
};
git.rebase().setUpstream("origin/"+branch).runInteractively(handler).call();
```

After this, I was able to keep my local changes on rebase, but the conflicting files are now getting overwritten with remote repository values.

And also the "conflicts list" and "failing path maps" of the RebaseResult are null, due to which I am not able to find the files updated also.

Am I doing something wrong here or is it an issue with JGit. I didn't get any proper docs also.

Comment: Regarding your second question (rebase with an InteractiveHandler): without a self-contained snippet it is impossible to tell why rebase does what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you found out that `git.pull().setRebase(true)` yields different results than native Git, you should [file a bug report](https://eclipse.org/jgit/support/).

Please note that you should provide a (failing) test case that asserts the expected result and the necessary steps to take with native git.